# SQL - Create column with default value in reference with a timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I'd like to create a column like for example 'post_date_col' in reference with 'pre_date_col'. I would like to field all the rows of the 'post_date_col' with a timestamp default value of 3 months after 'pre_date_col' column ('pre_date_col' is already fielded).

In a "static" way, I was thinking about something like this :

```
 INSERT INTO 'chosen_table'('post_date_col')
 VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(SELECT 'pre_date_col' FROM 'chosen_table', INTERVAL 90 DAY))
```

Is it possible to do it with pure SQL ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your quotes are broken.  You are using single quotes incorrectly.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in MySQL, without using a trigger.

Comment: yep thank you I didn't try this query. It was just an example

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're right ! thx

Comment: If you want the values to always be 90 day past the other timestamp and if you're already on MySQL 8.0 you could use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). If you want it as a mere default if no other value was specified or if you're on an older version of MySQL I'd agree with Tim, you'll most likely need a trigger.

Comment: @stickybit It sounds good, I will try to do so, thank you sir

Answer (score -1):

Just to answer you. I didn't find an "all in one" solution.
What I did is : 
-update the whole new column with the values of the past column
-add 3 months to new column's values
-convert it in timestamp

:-) thank you all